# Running PostgreSQL with Supervisord

Tags: postgresql, ubuntu, postgresql-9.1, supervisord

I want to run PostgreSQL 9.1 using Supervisor on Ubuntu 10.04. At the moment, I manually start PostgreSQL using the init script:

```
/etc/init.d/postgresql start
```

According to this post: http://nicksergeant.com/using-postgresql-with-supervisor-on-ubuntu-1010/, I need to modify the PostgreSQL config to make it run on TCP port instead of Unix socket, in order to make PostgreSQL work with Supervisor.

I have two questions regarding this approach:

1. Considering this is more of hack, is there any implication (e.g. security/permissions, performance, etc) of doing this?
2. Why cannot we just run the same init script `postgresql` in Supervisor config? Instead, as shown in the link above, it runs `postmaster`?

**UPDATE**:

Thanks to the useful suggestions from both answers below, I have setup a script for Supervisor to invoke PostgreSQL directly:

```
#!/bin/sh

# This script is run by Supervisor to start PostgreSQL 9.1 in foreground mode

if [ -d /var/run/postgresql ]; then
    chmod 2775 /var/run/postgresql
else
    install -d -m 2775 -o postgres -g postgres /var/run/postgresql
fi

exec su postgres -c "/usr/lib/postgresql/9.1/bin/postgres -D /var/lib/postgresql/9.1/main -c config_file=/etc/postgresql/9.1/main/postgresql.conf"
```

I also set the config: `/etc/postgresql/9.1/main/start.conf` to `manual` so that PostgreSQL does not start automatically on boot (however, it's not clear to me whether this config is loaded). And then I setup the Supervisor config for postgres as:

```
[program:postgres]
user=root
group=root
command=/usr/local/bin/run_postgresql.sh
autostart=true
autorestart=true
stderr_logfile=/home/www-data/logs/postgres_err.log
stdout_logfile=/home/www-data/logs/postgres_out.log
redirect_stderr=true
stopsignal=QUIT
```

So now, I can start PostgreSQL in `supervisorctl` by doing `start postgres`, which runs fine. **However, after I issue `stop postgres`, although `supervisorctl` declares postgres is stopped, the server apparently is still running as I can psql into it.**

I wonder if this is a Supervisor config issue, or a PostgreSQL issue. Any suggestion welcome!

Answer (score 3):

The blog post is rather badly written. There is no "TCP mode": the post's suggested method will still listen on a Unix socket, just in a different directory. Comments in the post such as "external pid file - not needed for TCP mode" are very misleading.

`postmaster` is the traditional name for the postgresql executable (to distinguish the master dispatching process from the backend slaves). For some time now there has been no separate executable, and now it is installed as simply "postgres".

Assuming that Supervisor is broadly simliar to the qmail/daemontools `supervise` scheme, it would be entirely possible (in fact, quite normal) to have it run a script that sets up the directories and environment, and then execs postgres with the requisite arguments (or propagates arguments given to the wrapper script, which would be unusual with supervise but makes more sense when you have a config file to put arguments into).

The way `supervise` worked (and I'm going to continue to assume "Supervisor" is the same) is to have the supervisor process run a subprocess as specified, and simply relaunch a new subprocess if it exits. This is based on the idea that the process being launched is a long-lived daemon process that only exits when something goes badly wrong, and that simply restarting it is a valid fix. By contrast, init scripts such as in `/etc/init.d` run the subprocess and detach it, and return control to their caller- if the subprocess exits, nothing special happens, and it must be restarted manually. If you tried to simply run `/etc/init.d/postgresql start` from supervise, it would continuously keep spawning postgresql daemons, as the return from the init script would be interpreted as the daemon process having exited, when in fact it had been started and detached.

Comment: thanks for you point on my second question, that was well explained! Relating to my first question (and your interpretation of what actually happens with the script in the link), are you suggesting that I should write a script that creates the necessary directory for postgresql and then runs `postmaster` (or `postgres`?) with the original postgresql config, and call this script instead in the Supervisor config file?

Comment: Right, you can have a shell script that basically does `[ -d /run/postgresql ] || make_rundir ; exec /usr/lib/postgresql/9.1/postgres "$@"` which will create the directory if required, then chain the `postgres` executable (`postmaster` being an obsolete name now). With supervise, this would literally have been called `run` inside the service directory.

Comment: Your assumption that `supervisord` works the same as `supervise` is correct; it'll start and respawn a subprocess for daemons under it's responsibility.

Answer (score 2):

To avoid auto-starting the service with the `/etc/init.d` scripts, the package for postgresql 9.1 provides a file `/etc/postgresql/9.1/main/start.conf` that contains:

```
# Automatic startup configuration
# auto: automatically start/stop the cluster in the init script
# manual: do not start/stop in init scripts, but allow manual startup with
#         pg_ctlcluster
# disabled: do not allow manual startup with pg_ctlcluster (this can be easily
#           circumvented and is only meant to be a small protection for
#           accidents).

auto
```

This is the file to modify to avoid auto-start as opposed to moving away  `/etc/init.d/postgresql` as the blog post suggests.

Also, changing unix sockets parameters for lack of `/var/run/postgresql` doesn't look like the best idea, because it's the default for any program linked with libpq, and because there's no difficulty in creating that directory with the proper permissions, just like it's done by the package's start sequence in `/usr/share/postgresql-common/init.d-functions`:

```
# create socket directory
if [ -d /var/run/postgresql ]; then
    chmod 2775 /var/run/postgresql
else
install -d -m 2775 -o postgres -g postgres /var/run/postgresql
fi
```

And although the default value shouldn't cause a problem, note that whether `postmaster` ultimately stays in foreground or forks and runs in background is controlled by the [silent_mode](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/runtime-config-logging.html#GUC-SILENT-MODE) parameter in `postgresql.conf`. Make sure that it is off.

Comment: thanks for the lengthy explanation. Two questions: 1. why do we want to avoid auto-starting `/etc/init.d/postgresql`? This is not clear to me in the original article; 2. Based on your answer above, it seems that only two things need to be changed to make this work with Supervisor: first, change to **manual** in `/etc/postgresql/9.1/main/start.conf`, and second, set 'silent_mode' parameter in `/etc/postgresql/9.1/main/postgresql.conf` **off**. Is that correct?

Comment: 1: if postgresql started on boot, it would be outside of the control of supervisor which contradicts the goal: to keep daemons under supervisor's control. 2: yes

Comment: I see. that's great! But I do need to create a script containing the portion you quoted above for creating necessary directory and setting permissions, and then call the postresql executable (btw, which executable should I be using: `/usr/lib/postgresql/9.1/bin/postgres` or `/usr/lib/postgresql/9.1/bin/pg_ctl`?)? And then run this script with Supervisor? thanks again!

Comment: Yes, you need to create that script. And it should launch `/usr/lib/postgresql/9.1/bin/postgres` (not pg_ctl) with at least the -D argument for the data directory.

Comment: thanks again. I've tried the above, with this line which invokes PostgreSQL: `exec /bin/su - postgres -c "/usr/lib/postgresql/9.1/bin/postgres -D /var/lib/postgresql/9.1/main -c config_file=/etc/postgresql/9.1/main/postgresql.conf`, which follows the directory creation/permission stuff as above. However, when I run the script via Supervisor, it fails and I get 'su: must be run from a terminal' in the log. Possibly permission problem with Supervisor?

Comment: @MLister I think you just want `su postgres -c ...` not `su - postgres -c ...` (the extra dash tries to set up a new login shell, which isn't really appropriate in this case)

Comment: @araqnid, thanks for pointing that out, so I changed it but it still complains the same message and the script failed (btw, in my comment above, there should have been a " in the end - just a typo) I suspect it's a file permission/ownership issue, and here are the details: `-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root`. They look fine to me.

Comment: @araqnid, update: so I change the user to root in Supervisor config file for running postgres, and now the script starts fine. However, when I try to stop it through Supervisor, i.e. `stop postgres` in supervisorctl, it doesn't seem to stop the server though it claims it does so... I wonder what happens.

Comment: @MLister is the postgres process directly owned by supervisord? (i.e. if you do `ps uaxf`, can you see that `postgres` is directly linked to `supervisord`). Looking at http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/server-shutdown.html SIGQUIT should work (although you may want a different `stopsignal` setting long term). If there's an extra shell process between `supervisord` and `postgres`, you may need an extra `exec` somewhere.

Comment: @MLister ah, if you were running su as non-root, it would want a terminal to ask for a password. Sometimes `sudo` works more easily as a way to run commands under different users.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/12855/discussion-between-mlister-and-araqnid)

Comment: @araqnid, actually the process tree shows that `postgres` is **not** linked to `supervisord`, but exists as a separate process. This may explain why `supervisord` fails to stop it. Is this because the wrapper script approach I use to invoke `postgres`?

Answer (score 2):

I am trying to make both tomcat and postgres run under supervisor, and found some hints here : https://serverfault.com/questions/425132/controlling-tomcat-with-supervisor

Here is my modified `run_postgresql.sh`, using bash :

```
#!/bin/bash

# This script is run by Supervisor to start PostgreSQL 9.1 in foreground mode

function shutdown()
{
    echo "Shutting down PostgreSQL"
    pkill postgres
}

if [ -d /var/run/postgresql ]; then
    chmod 2775 /var/run/postgresql
else
    install -d -m 2775 -o postgres -g postgres /var/run/postgresql
fi

# Allow any signal which would kill a process to stop PostgreSQL
trap shutdown HUP INT QUIT ABRT KILL ALRM TERM TSTP

exec sudo -u postgres /usr/lib/postgresql/9.1/bin/postgres -D /var/lib/postgresql/9.1/main --config-file=/etc/postgresql/9.1/main/postgresql.conf
```

With this script postgresql stops correctly after `supervisorctl stop postgres`.