# PostgreSQL with supervisor

Tags: bash, postgresql, shell, debian, supervisord

I wanted to know if it is possible to keep an eye on postgreSQL using [supervisor](http://supervisord.org/) on a debian server? I haven't been able to find any examples, so I am wondering if it is worth it, or perhaps there is a more straight forward way of ensuring it is always running.

Comment: See if you can adapt the check_postgres nagios plugin.

Comment: I would rather not use a different plugin

Answer (score 5):

See [Using PostgreSQL with Supervisor](http://nicksergeant.com/using-postgresql-with-supervisor-on-ubuntu-1010/) on Ubuntu 10.10 and the clarifications at [Running PostgreSQL with Supervisord](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11092358/running-postgresql-with-supervisord).  There are some useful examples in a [pastebin](http://pastebin.com/rhfh9V2g) too.  Given the common name of the program it can be hard to find these, the trick to getting examples is to search for supervisord instead.